# Definition for rule '@nrwl/nx/nx-plugin-checks' was not found

Tags: nrwl-nx, eslintrc, nrwl

Using NX v14.1.4, I'm trying to run linting on a lib that contains a custom executor and I get this error.

My config is:

```json
{
  "extends": ["../../.eslintrc.json"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["./package.json", "./generators.json", "./executors.json"],
      "parser": "jsonc-eslint-parser",
      "rules": {
        "@nrwl/nx/nx-plugin-checks": "error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The parent config is

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*"],
  "plugins": ["@nrwl/nx"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "enforceBuildableLibDependency": true,
            "allow": [],
            "depConstraints": [
              {
                "sourceTag": "*",
                "onlyDependOnLibsWithTags": ["*"]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/typescript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx"],
      "extends": ["plugin:@nrwl/nx/javascript"],
      "rules": {}
    },
    {
      "files": "*.json",
      "parser": "jsonc-eslint-parser",
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by adding `"@nx"`, short for `"@nx/eslint-plugin"`, in my plugins field in the root eslint config. Also, remember to install `@nx/eslint-plugin`

```json
{
  ...
  "plugins": [..., "@nx"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: This solved this issue for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was this:

Upgrade to NX 14.8.8, the way I did this was first uninstall all NX and nrwl:

```
npm uninstall nx @nrwl/cli @nrwl/devkit @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx @nrwl/jest @nrwl/js @nrwl/linter @nrwl/nest @nrwl/node @nrwl/nx-plugin @nrwl/workspace
```

Then, install 14.8.8 of those packages:

```
npm i -D nx@14.8.8 @nrwl/cli@14.8.8 @nrwl/devkit@14.8.8 @nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx@14.8.8 @nrwl/jest@14.8.8 @nrwl/js@14.8.8 @nrwl/linter@14.8.8 @nrwl/nest@14.8.8 @nrwl/node@14.8.8 @nrwl/nx-plugin@14.8.8 @nrwl/workspace@14.8.8
```

Confirm you are on 14.8.8:

```
nx --version
```

Now, the issue goes away. I suspect upgrading to beyond 14.8.8 would work as well.